# custom headers giving CORS error in PHP

Tags: php, cross-domain, cors, cross-domain-policy, custom-headers

I am  trying a REST based  cross domain request. both domain will be hosted on same server.

domain1: http://testdata.local - for the application which will request to REST API on domain2.

domain2: http://api.testdata.local - for handling the REST API calls from domain1

each rest api call have some custom headers which are required by domain2.

now when i call a rest API request to domain2 via ajax i am getting CORS blocked error.

below are my code which I am trying:

**PHP CODE for a sample api request on domain2:**

```
class mytest{

    public function setOriginPolicy() {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] == 'http://testdata.local') {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
            header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
        }
        // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            }
            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS'])) {
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:{$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
            }

            exit(0);
        }
    }

    public function testrequest(){
            $this->setOriginPolicy
            $result['config_status'] = 1;
            $result['config_msg'] = "request ok";
            echo json_encode($result);

    }
}
```

**AJAX Call from domain1:**

```
var url = "http://api.testdata.local/mytest/testrequest";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: true,
    crossDomain:true,
    //jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    headers:{"API_KEY":"andapikey","APP_VERSION":"1.0","CONFIG_VERSION":"1.0","AUTH_TOKEN": "4a6b1e610e81fa19c76a557049e9fa19"
    },
    /*beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("API_KEY", "andapikey"); 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("APP_VERSION", "1.0");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("CONFIG_VERSION", "1.0");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("AUTH_TOKEN", "4a6b1e610e81fa19c76a557049e9fa19");
    },*/
    success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

IF I disable the headers, I am getting the response.

Please suggest

Comment: I closed the string assigned to `url`, I hope that was not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

the solution:

Added custom header in allow origin headers in .htaccess.

Follwed the link http://benjaminhorn.io/code/setting-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-apache-with-correct-response-headers-allowing-everything-through/

Special thanks to benjamin.

Below is my .htaccess

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://testdata.local"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin,API_KEY,APP_VERSION,CONFIG_VERSION,AUTH_TOKEN"
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !OPTIONS
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```